# 2 x Netgear GS724T (Dual GBIC) trunking issue

Tags: networking, fiber, netgear

I have the following:

- Netgear GS724T (Firmware Version V1.0.3_35, Protocol Version - 2.001.002)
- 4 x Indineon ISFP GBR/FC

Settings

- STP Function - Enabled
- Fast Link - Enabled
- Trunking port 23,24, (21,22 - RJ45 cables, but not connected.)

I have connected both switches via 2 fiber cables and want to use trunking.

The problem I am having.

- Sometimes I get a an issue when none of the switches cannot talk with each other, nor the devices, sometime they can.
- The problem is irregular and no patten can be determined
- The statistics shows that when the switches does not work, they have RX errors

If I remove one to the GBIC connections, then everything works as normal.]

Question

- Does anyone have a solution for this please?

Thanks

Comment: Not up on Netgear but for a Cisco device you would setup the dual trunks as an Etherchannel connection.  STP should take care of any loops but I think you'll be better off with Etherchannel.

Comment: Hi, I do not think and I cannot find a Etherchannel on the netgear GS724T

Comment: From what I can find, those switches do not support Etherchannel/LACP.  If I were you I'd just stick with a single trunk.  Ref this link: http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=53402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, there hardly is a series of switches that sucks more than the NetGear "Smart Managed" one. I have indeed seen similar interoperability issues with trunking a GS724T and an Allied Telesis L2 switch, the technical support was less than helpful and in the end I decided to replace the device (the Netgear end) with a different make which cleared my problems.

After a couple of further unpleasant experiences, I decided not to touch Netgear "smart managed" again. Ever<sup>*</sup>. So if you really need the trunk I strongly suggest you think about alternative devices. Otherwise you might consider just using STP on two independent links - this would at least give you fault-tolerance unless you're fed up well enough to throw the switches into the next trash bin.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Not that other devices from the "cheapo Chinese-stamped" category are that much better. If you need predictability with your networking gear, stay with the "big" names.</sub>